# Resample image of sphere to match appearance of rotation

Tags: rendering, coordinates, fragment-shader

I am rendering sphere to a texture. Now, I have screen space texture, and I need to offset this texture based on screen space movement (dx, dy) and render it to a new texture.

For example, the left is my source image, movement is in "up" direction only (y-axis), and I need to end up with the image on the right. Data not presented on the left image after rotation remains empty.

[image: Source, Direction, Target]

I think I need to convert pixels in the right image to polar coordinates, apply an offset, convert them back and read pixels from the left image on this new position.

What I don't exactly know is how to apply the offset given in screen space to calculate the final position.

Note:
I have a world matrix used to render the original sphere, its radius and camera matrices (view, projection).
The camera is orthographic, static, put at (0, 0, offset) and with the target at (0, 0, 0) (also being the target of the sphere). I can pre-compute anything at CPU and pass it to the shader.

Comment: The full general solution to this may be more cumbersome than what you need. Are there any constrains we can apply to simplify the problem? For instance, this is much simpler if the camera is always orthographic. If not, then we can still have some simplification if the sphere sits along the axis of a perspective camera, not shifted off-center. Can we count on any of these things being true? It also helps clean up the shader code and improve efficiency if we can pre-compute some parameters CPU-side to pass as uniforms, but if that's not an option we can look at pure fragment shader versions.

Comment: Camera is orthographic, static, put at (0, 0, offset) and with target at (0, 0, 0) (also being the target of the sphere). I can pre-compute anything at CPU and pass it to shader